# Keycloak validate jwt token validation

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api

What is the latest endpoint to validate Keycloak access token.
In Keycloak 17.0.0 I used

```
{{Base_URL}}/realms/{{Realm_name}}/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo
```

GET method to validate token.. but in keycloak 20.0.1 it gives 403 (Forbidden). What is the latest way to validate the access token.